# How to Compile and Deploy Move smart contracts on Diem (Libra) Blockchain?

Tags: move-lang, diem

I know that compiling a Move source code is given on their documentation [here](https://developers.libra.org/docs/crates/ir-to-bytecode)

But how exactly do I deploy the binary to the network?

The simple command line at the moment does not have the deploy binary option.

Comment: The Move source language is in the early stages of development, and it is not released yet. So you can't deploy now. Source:https://developers.libra.org/docs/move-overview#future-developer-experience

Answer (score 1):

From the docs at https://developers.libra.org/docs/move-overview#future-developer-experience:

"The source language is in the early stages of development, and we do not have a timetable for its release yet."

Comment: Edit: You can still write move smart contracts and test them on your testnet. However, move currently does not allow for publishing modules. Check out my example at https://github.com/raguiar2/SafeCoin

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy your Move contract on your testnet.
Check out the example of `etoken-libra` which is ERC20-like token in Move on Libra
https://github.com/etoroxlabs/etoken-libra